# Express Javascript App, GET URL Error

Tags: javascript, forms, express, routes

I have an express app where I have a form on the page with a simple input.

index.ejs

```
 <form id="myForm" method="GET" action="">
    URL: <input type="text" name="url"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
  </form>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

  }
  </script>

<p>
    <%= content %>
</p>
```

When the form is submitted I just want it to go back to the exact same page because in my routes/index.js I'm grabbing the URL parameter and using it to parse the url string:

```
var url;
var content; 

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    url = req.query.url;

    some code to parse the url

    content = {what I got back from my parser}

    res.render('index', { 

        content: content,

    });      
});
```

So basically what happens is when I hit submit, the parameter in the url changes but the page gets a 500 error. From here, all I have to do is hit refresh (with the url parameter still in the URL) and everything works properly. My best guess is when I hit submit it's not fully refreshing the page with the URL parameter and re-running routes/index.js?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Fix the 500 error, so I don't have to hit submit, and then hit refresh.